# scraping data from next span within same h1 tag in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi i am trying to scrape subcategory

```
subcat = soup.find(class_='bread-block-wrap').find(class_='breadcrumb-keyword-bg').find(class_='breadcrumb-keyword list-responsive-container').find(class_='ui-breadcrumb').find('h1')
```

and this is the output

```
<h1>
<a href="//www.aliexpress.com/category/509/cellphones-telecommunications.html" title="Cellphones &amp; Telecommunications"> Cellphones &amp; Telecommunications</a>
<span class="divider">&gt;</span> <span> Mobile Phones</span>
</h1>
```

so now there is 2 span tag number 1 is

```
<span class="divider">&gt;</span>
```

and 2nd one is

```
<span> Mobile Phones</span>
```

and i want to scrape this text in 2nd span tag, please can someone help

Answer (score 1):

You can use [find_all()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) function to get all the span tags in a list and then use `.text` attribute to get the text.

```
subcat.find_all('span')[1].text
```

Should output

```
 Mobile Phones
```

Demo

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<h1>
<a href="//www.aliexpress.com/category/509/cellphones-telecommunications.html" title="Cellphones &amp; Telecommunications"> Cellphones &amp; Telecommunications</a>
<span class="divider">&gt;</span> <span> Mobile Phones</span>
</h1>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
h1=soup.find('h1')
print(h1.find_all('span')[1].text.strip())
```

Output

```
Mobile Phones
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a fast response, can u help me with 1 more thing, how do i remove  \\ before \\xyz.com

Comment: @MuhammadFaisal Okay I got your question now. You can get the correct url from href by  `subcat.find('a')['href'].replace('//','')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use css nth-of-type selector

```
h1 span:nth-of-type(2)
```

i.e.

```
items = soup.select("h1 span:nth-of-type(2)")
```

Then iterate list.

If only one match possible then simply:

```
item = soup.select_one("h1 span:nth-of-type(2)")
print(item.text.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be using CSS selectors which lets you get rid of cascading over and over again. In your case this:

```
results = soup.select(".bread-block-wrap .breadcrumb-keyword-bg .breadcrumb-keyword.list-responsive-container .ui-breadcrumb h1 span")
```

is going to return the two `span` tags in a list. Then, you can simply just use the second one.

You, of course, have lots of other useful tools to work with when you choose CSS selectors. Just find a CSS selector cheatsheet and enjoy.